# How can I tell whether to show less GPU-intensive graphics on my page?

Tags: javascript, mobile, graphics, feature-detection, device-detection

I have a webpage which has some visual effects on it that I think really enhance it. However, they are somewhat GPU intensive. For any desktop, they're child's play. However, on my laptop and phone, the devices heat up rather fast.

I don't want to harm my users' devices, nor cause them to heat up, nor run their fans just because they're viewing my page. However, I don't want to abandon these effects entirely. **How can I tell whether it's OK to use these effects, versus when I should use the fallback?**

My first instinct was to query [the Battery Status API]`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API)`, but that is highly discouraged and basically only works in Chromium now. I don't know any alternative way to ask "is this a laptop or a desktop?" or "does this have enough GPU power to handle this confidently?"

Comment: Checking the user agent might be one option, though that'll only tell you the system the client is using, not how much power their setup has. (also, it's forgeable, so it's not 100% reliable)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I also considered that... but I couldn't find any differences between laptop and desktop